# Detect when ScrollBar Maximum is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar

Simple question. Having:

```
<ScrollBar ... />
```

How can I detect when `Maximum` is changed? E.g. for `Value` there is an [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.valuechanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Typically there would be a binding of some kind. I was thinking maybe it is possible to get this binding, create dependency property and bind to it instead, then I can register a callback when this new dependency property is changed... but that sounds complicated nor I am sure it is acceptable solution to all cases (e.g. what if another binding is set, how can I detect this kind of change). Polling?

Comment: i'd create a usercontrol inherited from ScrollBar and override the Maximum property to raise an event.

Comment: @SebastianL, good idea, simply overriding [`OnMaximumChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.onmaximumchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) to rise custom event may work. Any solution without custom control?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom class such as:

```
public class MScrollBar : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollBar
{ 

    protected override void OnMaximumChanged(double oldMaximum, double newMaximum)
    {
        // do stuff
        base.OnMaximumChanged(oldMaximum, newMaximum);
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class MScrollBar : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollBar
{
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Property == System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollBar.MaximumProperty)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);

    }
}
```

Comment: In my case `ScrollBar` was already a part of control template, so I can't use custom control (unless redefining a complete control template). But someone else may find the answer useful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand what **any** property can be a **source** for multiple bindings. We can create a new target (new dependency property) which is then perfectly able to report about any change done to a property:

1. Create a new dependency property with callback.
2. Bind it to any other property to monitor for changes.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public double Maximum
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(0, (d, e) =>
        {
            // value has changed
        }));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var scrollBar = ... // instance of scrollbar
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, MaximumProperty,
            new Binding(nameof(RangeBase.Maximum)) { Source = scrollBar });
    }
}
```